# How to handle empty hash literal into devops pipeline variable

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, hashtable, azure-powershell

I have one DevOps release pipeline. When I update my app service it automatically deletes any app configuration added previously by the user.
So I want to get all the app settings and store them into variable then after the app service update again add them back to the app setting.

**To store app setting into variable**

```
$webApp = Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $(Parameter.ResourceGroupName) -Name $(Parameters.AppName)  
$appSetting = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$hash = @{}
foreach($kvp in $appSetting) {
    $hash[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
}
Write-Host ($hash | Out-String)
$jsonObject = [PSCustomObject]$hash
$convertJson = $jsonObject | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 100 -Compress
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=storeAppSetting;]$convertJson"
```

Note: When I print $hash, it successfully prints all the key-value pairs.

**Now I want to use that variable to set the app setting again**

```
$hashtable = @{}
$hashtable = $(storeAppSetting) | ConvertFrom-JSON -Depth 100 -AsHashtable
Write-Host ($hashtable | Out-String)
Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $(Parameter.ResourceGroupName) -Name $(Parameters.AppName) -AppSettings $hashtable
```

Both are azure PowerShell steps in the release pipeline. No error was faced in the first step and successfully stored the hashtable into the variable. In the second step, the error is displayed because one of the key value is empty.

```
+ ... 1000ae7f7; EnterpriseRedisAccess=true; RedisConnectionString=; d=d; S ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing statement after '=' in hash literal.
```

Any suggestion how can I handle this?

Comment: $hashtable =  $hashtable | ConvertFrom-JSON -Depth 100 -AsHashtable

Comment: All the settings should be in 'storeAppSetting' variable. I think we need to deserialize this.

Comment: Able to resolve the original issue. Now another error is coming. Updated the description.

Comment: wouldn't that mean `$kvp.Value` is null? how about testing for it first then assigning `$null` to it if it's not there?